# npm update adds "dev:true" in package-lock.json

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, package.json, npm-update

I'm auditing the packages in my project. I want to address vulnerability for each package separately rather than running `npm audit fix`. Most of the vulnerabilities are in the dependencies and not in the main package which is installed. For example I have installed package `foo`, it added dependencies for it in the `package-lock.json` ie `bar:1.1.0` etc. Now the vulnerability is for `bar` which is fixed in patch `version:1.1.1`. so to fix it I'm updating the package using `npm update bar`.

On running the update command the `package-lock.json` is flooded with version updates for packages some of which are not relevant to `bar` and changes more than 200 lines in the lock file. Also, the `npm update` or `npm audit fix` command adds `"dev": true` in almost all the package definition which was not present earlier.

[image]

**Question**

Is there any way that `npm update` not adds the `"dev": true` in unwanted places or how can I update a single package at a time which will keep my commits clean and easy to track.

I have tried the command `npm update foo --omit=dev`, but it did not worked.

Comment: Well, is `yocto-queue` a development dependency, either directly or transitively?

Comment: @AKX  no it is not a development dependency in any configuration, neither the main package .